# Parsing image URLs in remote HTML as JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asp-classic, xmlhttprequest

I am looking to create a URL sharer similar to that of LinkedIn and Facebook where you paste a  URL in and pull remote content across with a scroller of the available images to use?

[image: LinkedIn example]

Basically my idea is that I need to pull HTML from the remote URL using my server side XMLHTTP script I then want to be able to check for any images (over a certain width / height - e.g. No transpixels get loaded.)

Is it possible to load all the remote HTML as escapable JSON and then use Jquery to check for suitable images to stick in the scroller?

Comment: You'd be better off using a parser to search for `<img>` elements and getting their `src` attribute.

Comment: How do you suggest I do that? Cheers

Comment: I don't really know within the tags of the question. In PHP I'd use `DOMDocument`.

Comment: In php, you may want to try [phpquery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this directly becasue of same origin policy, you will be able to use iframe to fetch web page but you can't read it's content. you need simple server script that will be a proxy. If you use php and it allow to open urls as files you will be able to use this:

```php
<?php 

if (isset($_GET['url'])) {
   echo json_encode(get_file_contents($_GET['url']));
}
```

and then using ajax you can fetch pages using urls and you can use jquery as a parser.

```
$.getJSON('fetch.php', {url: "http://google.pl"}, function(html) {
   $(html).find('img');
});
```